# Use of PerformanceCounters with good results

Tags: c#, winforms

I am struggling a bit using performancecounters. Some counters always result in 0 first, so i got an idea to basicly just do a sleep.thread for 1 second before assigning the value to a field.

But then i got problems with performance, so i read some tips and i should write it like this:

```
    private PerformanceCounter pcMemory;
    private void InitPerfmem()
    {
        this.pcMemory = new PerformanceCounter();
        this.pcMemory.CategoryName = "Memory";
        this.pcMemory.CounterName = "Available MBytes";
        this.pcMemory.CounterName = "Page Faults/sec";
        this.pcMemory.NextValue();
    }


    private PerformanceCounter pcProcess;
    private void InitPerfCPU()
    {
        this.pcProcess = new PerformanceCounter();
        this.pcProcess.CategoryName = "Processor";
        this.pcProcess.CounterName = "Interrupts/sec";
        this.pcProcess.InstanceName = "_Total";
        this.pcProcess.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        this.pcProcess.InstanceName = "_Total";
        this.pcProcess.NextValue();
    }


    private void tmrProcess_Tick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        cpInt.Text = this.pcProcess.NextValue().ToString();
        cpPower.Text = this.pcProcess.NextValue().ToString() + "%"; //Display

    }



    private void tmrMemory_Tick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        pgFaults.Text = this.pcMemory.NextValue().ToString();
        avlMem.Text = this.pcMemory.NextValue().ToString();

    }
```

Will this work in avoiding the first result which is zero? I also get an error "Object referense is not set to an instance of an object"
Tried reading countless articles on this but most are focused on using a button that refreshes that date. My timers are set to always enabled and refresh interval at 1 second to provide more of a realtime tool, just like Performance Monitor in windows.

Anyone who can push me in the right direction here?

Comment: Are you calling `InitPerfmem()` or `InitPerfCPU()` anywhere in your code? I can't see it in your example... Not initializing the `PerformanceCounter` objects would certainly cause the `Object reference` error. If you *have* called these methods, then which line throws the error? What do you mean `the first result which is zero`? The first time you access `NextValue`? Please be clear.

Comment: First time calling NextValue